# Git subtree & remote information not available to other users

Tags: git-subtree

Git subtree & remote information is missing from .git/config file on workspaces other than the committed workspace.

Other users who pulled the git repo are not able to see the remote repo information in their .git/config file

They are not able to update or modify the subtrees.

I used the following commands to add the subtree

$ git remote add -f github.com/google/cadvisor https://github.com/google/cadvisor.git

$ git merge -s ours --no-commit github.com/google/cadvisor/master

$ git read-tree --prefix=github.com/google/cadvisor -u github.com/google/cadvisor/master

$ git commit -m ""

What is the best way to get it working?

Comment: I've been looking at git subtree myself. It seems this is the expected behavior. Anyone that wants to push back to the upstream subtrees needs to tell git about the subtree before pushing. Kind of a pain.

Comment: Thanks Tom. We will store this in the repo for now in that case.